# Is $37!$ divisible by $19!\cdot20!$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factorial

> Is $37!$ divisible by $19!\cdot20!$ ?

I rewrite it as $\frac{37!}{19!*20!}=\frac{37*36*35*...*21}{19!}$

simplified it and got $\frac{37*35*33*31*29*23}{19}$ what is obvious is not integer.

Another way, I noticed that fraction $\frac{37*36*35*...*21}{19!}$
 numerator doesn't have a multiple of $19$, so $19\nmid 37*36*35*...*21$

But I believe that it should be more general way to prove it. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: $19$ is prime. The number of numbers less than or equal to $37$ that are divisible by $19$ are $[37/19]$. The number of those that are divisible by $19^2$ are $[37/19^2]=0$. This means that the maximum exponent $k$ such that $19^k$ divides $37!$ is $[37/19]=1$. However, $19$ divides both $20!$ and $19!$.

Comment: Personally, I think your argument involving $19$ is optimal.  As a general method, I'd study the order to which various primes divides the denominator...for which you can always use [de polignac's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula)

Comment: In other words, the idea that is useful for other problems is that the exponent to which a prime $p$ appears in the factorization of $n!$ is $[n/p]+[n/p^2]+[n/p^3]+...$

Comment: I agree with lulu that this is close to optimal. Putting your solution another way, the prime factorization of $19! 20!$ has two factors of $19$, but the prime factorization of $37!$ only has one, therefore the latter is not divisible by the former.

Comment: Just to say, the denominator is $2^{34}×3^{16}×5^7×7^4×11^2×13^2×17^2×19^2$ while the numerator is $2^{34}×3^{17}×5^8×7^5×11^3×13^2×17^2×19×23×29×31×37$ so the only prime that interferes with the division is $19$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$ \frac {37!}{19!20!}$$ is not an integer

We know that there are two $19$ in the bottom but only one in the top.

Since $19$ is prime the fraction does not simplify to an integer.

Comment: The OP already knows of this argument. Also see lulu's comment to Jack Pfaffinger's tactfully deleted answer.